# Convert linq query result to dataview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm querying the database and returning a row.

```
var p = (from prop in db.tabe 
         where prop.pid == 1
         select prop);
```

However I'd like to take the result and insert that into a dataview. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

"Creating a DataView from a query that returns anonymous types or queries that perform join operations is not supported."

So that is not supported, why don't you use List instead:

```
 var list =  (from prop in db.tabe 
              where prop.pid == 1
              select prop).ToList();
```

Comment: This is correct and probably why i'm having issues. How can i convert the list to a dataview?

Comment: Where do you wan't to use? Maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: I just went with a function I had previously for passing a sql query text and returning a dataview. thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, no probs. Leave the dataview, if it's possible. Work with generics.

Answer (score 1):

You [can do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669080%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DataView view = p.AsDataView();

bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the result as a dataview you should be able to do this:

```
Dataview pDV = p.AsDataView();
```

This should be a full detail example and additional assistance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
DataView v = new p.AsDataView();
```

or

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in p)
    t.Rows.Add(dataRow);
DataView v = new DataView(t);
```